# Programmatically exporting .PBIX files to .PDF

Tags: pdf, powerbi-desktop, converters

I'm struggling to use the Power BI API to programmatically download multiple reports into a pdf file format. I've written a short powershell script that connects to my accounts and produces a list of all available reports then exports the list as a csv. As there is no 'Export-pdf' attribute is there a work around? Here is my script below.

{

Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount

$myWorkspaces = Get-PowerBIWorkspace
Write-Host “The current user has –” $myWorkspaces.Count “– workspaces.”

$Reports =
ForEach ($workspace in $Workspaces)
    {

```
Write-Host $workspace.Name
ForEach ($report in (Get-PowerBIReport -Scope Individual -WorkspaceId $workspace.Id))
    {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        WorkspaceID = $workspace.Id
        WorkspaceName = $workspace.Name
        ReportID = $report.Id
        ReportName = $report.Name
        ReportURL = $report.WebUrl
        ReportDatasetID = $report.DatasetId
        }
    }
}
```

Write-Host “The current user has –” $Reports.Count “– reports.”

$Reports | Export-csv -Path C:\Users\jackbolshaw\Desktop\eTech\Test\report.csv -NoTypeInformation

Disconnect-PowerBIServiceAccount

}